# jquery insertbefore

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jQuery question.

How come I can't do this?

```
$("<div class='flora'></div>").insertBefore('</body>');
```

I just want to add a new div at the end of the HTML page.  So I thought I'd use the .insertBefore method, but jQuery seems to not like to target the `</body>` tag.

thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: In short, where you have `'</body>'`, you need a selector.  Because of this, `insertBefore()` won't work for your needs.  Hence the suggestion of `append()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like

```
$('body').append("<div class='flora'></div>");
```

And if you really want to append before something... you can use the before() method.

```
$('something').before("<div class='flora'></div>");
```

Comment: You can also use $("<div class='flora'></div>").appendTo('body');

Comment: Thank Boushley.  I found this out only a couple of minutes after posting this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [.append()](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append#content) method instead.

> http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append
>
> "Append content to the inside of every matched element.
> This operation is the best way to insert elements inside, at the end, of all matched elements. It is similar to doing an appendChild to all the specified elements, adding them into the document."

Comment: Hehe. No problem, man :) Brilliant minds think alike - we both happen to know the answer to that one, and you were rewarded for it, as you should be :)